# MongoDB map reduce find anagrams

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have problems with mongodb. I have to write some js code to find anagrams in my collection lista. The collection structure is as follows:

{_id : value, Import: anagram }

The code below acrually does its work - it finds anagrams but I have to do it using map reduce manner.
I have tried many times to rewrite this code as map reduce but I didn't manage. I know the concept, I tried doing it like so :

```
db.lista.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    {
        out : "result"
    }
);
```

but no result. How the code should be splitted? How to do that? How to save output to a database?
Any help would be gratly appreciated.

```
var input = db.lista.find().sort( { Import: 1} );
var anagrams = {};

input.forEach(function(word) {
    var alphabetical = word.Import.split("").sort().join("");
    var oryginal = word.Import;
    var sorted = alphabetical;

    if (anagrams[sorted] != null) {
        anagrams[sorted].push(word);
    } 
    else {
        anagrams[sorted] = [ word ];
    }
});

for (var sorted in anagrams) {
    var words = anagrams[sorted];
    var sep = ",";
    var out = "";
    for (var n in words) {
        out += sep + words[n];
        sep = "";
    }
    print(sorted + ": " + out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `map-reduce` as below:

- The `map` function should `emit` the sorted order string as `key` and an
  array of words as `value`.

Code:

```
var map = function(){
    var alphabetical = this.import.split("").sort().join("");
    emit(alphabetical,{"words":[this.import]})
}
```

- The `reduce` function, for each key and a group of words, just
  accumulates the words and returns them.

Code:

```
var reduce = function(key,value){
    var result = {"words":[]};
    value.forEach(function(word){
    result["words"] = result["words"].concat(word["words"]);
    })
    return result;
}
```

Invoke the `map-reduce` on the collection.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"s"});
```

Fetch the output from the collection where the results are dumped.

`db.s.find()` would give you the following sample result.

```
{ "_id" : "adeippr", "value" : { "words" : [ "prepaid" ] } }
{ "_id" : "ckor", "value" : { "words" : [ "rock", "cork" ] } }
{ "_id" : "clo", "value" : { "words" : [ "clo", "loc" ] } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. You helped me a lot with your expertise.